# How to send custom messages to all group participants using whatsapp-web.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

I want to send individual custom messages to all participants in a group using whatsapp-web.js

For that my first aproach is to get the particiopant's names and phone numbers

I tryed to get the info by using getContactById method but contacts attributes are empty

```js
if (msg.body === '!contactosgrupo') {
        let chats=await client.getChats();
        const chat=chats.find(
            (chat)=>chat.name==="My Group" 
        );
        if (chat.isGroup) {
            chat.participants.forEach(function(item){
                let contacto=client.getContactById(item.id._serialized);//I tryed to send id and id.user none worked
                console.log(JSON.stringify(contacto) );
                console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                //Here I'd like to send a custom message like 'Hello [NAME OF THE CONTACT] have a nice day'...
            });

        }
```